# Capture cookie of a 302 redirect response? (Cross Domain)

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain

Situation: I have simple html page which does a form post via AJAX to a php page with user credentials which when successfully validated sets cookies and does a 302 redirect to a success page(200).

When I do a ajax call, success method is called only when success page is reached and returns me the status code of 200. But I need to capture the cookie which 302 redirect sets in the response and need to validate it. I don't have control over success page though.

I tried

```
     $.ajaxSetup({complete: onRequestCompleted});

     function onRequestCompleted(xhr,textStatus) {
     if (xhr.status == 302) {
      //capture cookie from xhr
      }
      }
```

But it does not seem to called when 302 happens. Is there a way to achieve this?

Note:

- It's a cross domain request and server settings have been enabled to serve cross origin requests.
- Have enabled crossdomain to true and withCredentials to true in client side.